# How to pass each component id

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I want to implement dragging components (beautiful dnd) so that the user can swap them. But for this, each component must have an id, as I understand it. But I do not know how to do it

```
import React from 'react';
import CardWeather from '../cardWeather/CardWeather';
import WeatherMap from '../cardWeatherMap/WeatherMap';
import Forecast from '../forecast/Forecast';
import WeatherGrapth from '../weatherGraph/WeatherGraph';
import './main.scss';
import { Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

const Main = () => {

    return (
      <>
      <Droppable droppableId="main">
        {
          (provided) => (
            <div className="main-container"
            ref={provided.innerRef} 
            {...provided.droppableProps}
            >
            <CardWeather />
            <Forecast/>
            <WeatherGrapth/>
            <WeatherMap/>
        </div>
          )
        }

      </Droppable>


        <div className="pr">weather app</div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: if you add sample in https://codesandbox.io/ better for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get this correctly you need to have some kind of id for every component in your case:

```
 <CardWeather />
 <Forecast/>
 <WeatherGrapth/>
 <WeatherMap/>
```

You can pass the id by props for each component. Example:

**Main component:**

```
  <CardWeather id="1" />
```

**CardWeather component:**

```
function CardWeather(props){
  const id = props.id
  ...
  return(
    <div data-id={id}>
    ...
    </div>
  )
}
...
```

And you have to do that for every component you want to drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

- Hi, to do that you also need to use Draggable Component importing from 'react-beautiful-dnd'.
- And also if you don't have unique ids for your items you can use 'react-uuid' package to pass through to 'draggableId'. It will create unique ids for you.
- And also I am highly recommending to you watch this course about "react-beautiful-dnd". This course was created by who developed "react-beautiful-dnd".
  https://egghead.io/courses/beautiful-and-accessible-drag-and-drop-with-react-beautiful-dnd

`import React from 'react';
import CardWeather from '../cardWeather/CardWeather';
import WeatherMap from '../cardWeatherMap/WeatherMap';
import Forecast from '../forecast/Forecast';
import WeatherGrapth from '../weatherGraph/WeatherGraph';
import './main.scss';
import { Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import uuid from 'react-uuid';

const Main = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <Droppable droppableId="main">
                {
                    (provided) => (
                        <Draggable
                            draggableId={uuid()}
                            index={"element index"}
                        >
                            {(provided, snapshot) => {
                                <div className="main-container"
                                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                                    {...provided.droppableProps}
                                    isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
                                >
                                    <CardWeather />
                                    <Forecast />
                                    <WeatherGrapth />
                                    <WeatherMap />
                                </div>
                            }}
                        </Draggable>
                    )
                }

            </Droppable>
            <div className="pr">weather app</div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Main;
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

It's best to have also a key prop to each component. So that if I'd changes you will get a rerender.